# aSyncTask with CameraDemo and Preview gives looper error

Tags: android

I am using the CamneraDemo sample as part of an Android project.   I have put the CameraDemo code inside an aSyncTask and from there it creates a new Preview.   The code for the Preview class creates a SurfaceView and since I moved the CameraDemo code into the aSyncTask I get the 'cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()'  I have googeld around this and seen suggestions re using a runnable but can't get my head around how to do that with the aSyncTask situation.

Comment: Post some sample code and the logcat.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you creating the `SurfaceView`? You should be creating views on the UI thread, which means your `SurfaceView` creation code should be in [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) or one of the other `AsyncTask` methods that are executed on the UI thread.